# std::invoke для неполного типа

Tags: c++, visual-c++, gcc, clang

Почему clang не компилирует этот код https://godbolt.org/z/co7hheM3v?

```
#include <functional>

struct Incomplete;
Incomplete&& give();
void take(Incomplete&&);

void okay() {
    take(give());
}

void bad() {
    std::invoke(take, give());
}
```

> error: no matching function for call to 'invoke'

Comment: Ну и откуда он должен взять адрес функции которых нет?

Comment: похоже clang тут ни при чём (сам же видишь, что с libc++ он собирается нормально… да и gcc фейлится аналогично)… выглядит как баг в libstdc++…

Comment: и если что, баг, похоже ещё не зарепорчен…

Comment: Я так понял, код взяли из [этой статьи](https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2021/12/27/libstdcxx-what-are-you-doing/). Разве там нет объяснения?

Answer (score 0):

Это UB, но какое-то странное. Выглядит как баг в стандарте.

**[`std::invoke`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_invocable)**:

> This overload participates in overload resolution only if `std::is_invocable_v<F, Args...>` is true.

**[`std::is_invocable`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_invocable)** `<class Fn, class... ArgTypes>`:

> `Fn`, `R` and all types in the parameter pack `ArgTypes` shall each be a complete type, (possibly cv-qualified) `void`, or an array of unknown bound. **Otherwise, the behavior is undefined.**